# Follow Link in Fundamental Mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

How can I emulate a mouse-click on a link in plain Emacs fundamental mode?

For example I want to click the link to the Tutorial on the fancy-startup-screen.

I tried to google that seemingly very simple question, but to my surprise, I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the cursor is over the link you want to click.
Make sure, that you are not in another mode, which may not be obvious, like "evil mode".

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thank you for taking the time to post a self-answer question, but could you [edit] and elaborate a little? It's not clear where just hitting 'enter' works, nor what it does.

Comment: Thank you for the nice comment. :) Of course i will elaborate :)